# Convert spark dataframe to sparklyR table "tbl_spark"

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm trying to convert spark dataframe `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` to a sparklyr table `tbl_spark`. I tried with `sdf_register`, but it failed with following error.

In here, df is spark dataframe.

```
sdf_register(df, name = "my_tbl")
```

error is,

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: my_tbl; line 2 pos 17
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.getTable(Analyzer.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:315)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
```

Have I missed anything? or Is there any better way to convert it to `tbl_spark`?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This piece of code alone won't cause the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sdf_copy_to()` or `dplyr::copy_to()`, e.g. `my_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, df, "my_tbl")`