# How to convert from SparkR to sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, sparkr, sparklyr

How do I convert a `SparkDataFrame` from `SparkR` into a `tbl_spark` from `sparklyr`?

A similar question was asked here: [Convert spark dataframe to sparklyR table "tbl_spark"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288775/convert-spark-dataframe-to-sparklyr-table-tbl-spark).

The suggestion was to use the sdf_copy_to function, however, the input of this function must be an R object in instead of a `SparkDataFrame`.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a temp Spark table to convert from `SparkR::SparkDataFrame` to `sparklyr::tbl_spark`.

Starting with a `SparkDataFrame` in `SparkR`

```
df_sparkr <- SparkR::createDataFrame(data.frame(
  x = 1:10
))
```

Create a temp table in Spark

```
SparkR::registerTempTable(df_sparkr, "temp_df")
```

Read the table using `sparklyr`

```
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(master = "local")
df_sparklyr <- dplyr::tbl(sc, "temp_df")
```

---

Here is a second method if your data is small. You can convert to a normal R data frame then copy into `sparklyr`. This is not recommended if the data frame is large.

```
df_normal <- SparkR::collect(df_sparkr)
df_sparklyr <- dplyr::copy_to(sc, df_normal)
```

Comment: the registerTempTable (createOrReplaceTempView now) doesn't work because the spark context is different between SparkR and sparklyR. There's no good way to be able to do this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54381583/2019736) that explains.